# Cancelling paypal subscriptions using their API - how to keep the account active for the already paid peroid?

Tags: paypal, paypal-subscriptions, paypal-webhooks

I am currently integrating Paypal subscriptions into my ReactJS WebApp.

A user shall be able to subscribe (and pay a small fee) to use premium features.

I wonder how to handle cancellations. What I would expect is when a user subscribes for a one-year period and then immediately cancels, he/she shall still be able to use the service for the paid period (one year).

With my current solution, however, upon cancelling, the access to premium features vanish immediately and does not let the user to access the service he paid for(and cancelled later).

My current solution looks like this:

- Subscribing already works by using this paypal button: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-paypal-button-v2#subscription-example-usage
- Cancelling also works using this API call: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/subscriptions/full-integration/subscription-management/#cancel-subscription
  This also triggers a webhook of my app with the event `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED`. Then **immediately the account is cancelled** and the user cannot use the features he already paid for.

How do the events `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.CANCELLED`, `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.EXPIRED`, `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.SUSPENDED`, `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` relate to each other ? I did not find any documentation about his.
Is there an event or a workflow that I can use to accomplish what I intend ? I currently develop this using the sandbox features.

Or do I have to implement the necessary logic by myself?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PayPal only keeps track of whether the subscription is active.

Cancelled or Expired are *how* it became inactive.

On cancellation, you need to implement any "already paid for" logic yourself, PayPal does not do this.

Comment: Hi Preston, thanks for your anwser! I wonder how the "expired" state is reached then, I think it cannot be triggered by the rest API?
Given this, I would store the remaining time directly upon subscription. Is there any webhook which is called when a new billing cycle starts?

Comment: The expired state is reached when it reaches the end of a finite number of cycles.  When a cycle is successfully payed for you'll receive a PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED, per https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api-basics/notifications/webhooks/event-names/#subscriptions

Comment: Finally got it running. I did not use `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.EXPIRED` because I use infinite subscriptions. I also ignored `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.SUSPENDED` and `BILLING.SUBSCRIPTION.ACTIVATED` because they seem optional. The solution for me was listening to `PAYMENT.SALE.COMPLETED`, fetching the details from the subscription the payment has been made for and store `billing_info.next_billing_time` in my apps database. Thanks again!